# Can't connect AWS RDS using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js

When I use this code, I can connect successfully to my AWS RDS postgre

```
import pg from "pg";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

(async () => {
  try {
    const client = new pg.Client({
      host: process.env.PG_HOST,
      port: process.env.PG_PORT,
      user: process.env.PG_USER,
      password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
      ssl: true,
    });

    await client.connect();
    const res = await client.query("SELECT $1::text as connected", [
      "Connection to postgres successful!",
    ]);
    console.log(res.rows[0].connected);
    await client.end();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error);
  }
})();
```

But now I want to use sequelize and I try this code

```
import "dotenv/config.js";
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

const dbConfig = {
  HOST: process.env.PG_HOST,
  USER: process.env.PG_USER,
  PASSWORD: process.env.PG_PASSWORD + "",
  DB: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
  PORT: process.env.PG_PORT, 
  dialect: "postgres",
  // ssl: true,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
};

console.log(dbConfig.USER);

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  port: dbConfig.PORT, 
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

export default db;
```

I got errors:

```
 Cannot connect to the database! ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "118.70.42.38", user "postgres", database "My_first", no encryption
```

and

original: error:

```
 no pg_hba.conf entry for host "118.70.42.38", user "postgres", database "My_first", no encryption
```

.

I'm not sure why this happens. Maybe there is a problem with Sequelize? Any support would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is saying that, for some reason, SSL is turned off -- even though you appear to have requested that it be turned on. I frequently see this error when SSL is False. So, your mission is to figure out how to get it to set SSL to True. This _might_ help: [How to connect via SSL to sequelize DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449386/174777) or even: [How to configure sequalize & node mysql to use new aws rds root cert rds-ca-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348414/174777)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in a `dialectOptions` object has worked for me in the past which would look like:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  port: dbConfig.PORT, 
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  dialectOptions: { //< Add this
     ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
     }
  }
});
```

This could be moved into your `dbConfig` object but I'll leave that up to you.

See the [Dialect-Specific Things](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/#postgresql) for PostgreSQL for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a conclusive answer, but i will add for other people in the future, i've been experiencing the same error, but a comment was given that helps tremendously.

dialect options are found here in the sequelize docs, but they are not a complete list:

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/#postgresql

sequelize depends on an underlying library PG for postgres, which has these options:
https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl

the dialect options belong to a node library found here, with more dialect options: https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket

the ones most commonly seen in examples found online are found here:
https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions

these 4 links provide 100% of the context for dialect options