# Sequelize breaks, but PG doesnt with matching config

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

piggybacking on this post: [Can't connect AWS RDS using sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741037/cant-connect-aws-rds-using-sequelize/78202153#78202153)

I am experiencing the same error, but am thoroughly confused over what's happening.

#### the following connection with `pg` *works*

```js
const pg = require('pg')

// ...

async function pgExample () {
  try {
    const client = new pg.Client({
      host: DB_HOST,
      port: DB_PORT,
      user: DB_USER,
      password: DB_PASS,
      database: DB_NAME,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    })

    await client.connect()
    const res = await client.query("SELECT $1::text as connected", [
      "Connection to postgres successful!",
    ])
    console.log(res.rows[0].connected)
    await client.end()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error)
  }
}
pgExample()

// this works
```

but the following `sequelize` code does not work

```js
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')

// ...

async function sequelizeExample () {
  try {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, {
      host: DB_HOST,
      port: DB_PORT,
      database: DB_NAME,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
      }
    })

    await sequelize.sync()
    console.log('Connection to postgres successful!')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error)
  }
}
sequelizeExample()

// this breaks
```

I have also tried alternative configurations, like

```js
const URI = `postgres://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@${DB_HOST}/${DB_NAME}`

const sequelize = new Sequelize(URI, {
  database: DB_NAME,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
})
```

---

the error:

```bash
Error occurred: ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "##.###.##.###", user "####", database "####", no encryption
    at Client._connectionCallback (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:145:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:327:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:347:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at /Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:12
    at Parser.parse (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9) {
  parent: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "##.###.##.###", user "####", database "####", no encryption
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 160,
    severity: 'FATAL',
    code: '28000',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'auth.c',
    line: '542',
    routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
  },
  original: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "##.###.##.###", user "####", database "####", no encryption
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/aronlilland/Downloads/example/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 160,
    severity: 'FATAL',
    code: '28000',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'auth.c',
    line: '542',
    routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
  }
}
```